# Using lambda function in MongoDB $where clause in Java

Tags: javascript, java, mongodb, lambda

I'm trying to execute JavaScript equivalent query in Java using the $where clause.
The JavaScript query looks like this:

```
var currDate = new ISODate()
db.getCollection('rides')
.find(
{
        "startDate" : {
            "$lte" : currDate
        },
        "stopDate" : {
            "$gte" : currDate
         },
        $where : function() { return (this.weekday == new Date(new ISODate().getTime() + this.timeOffset).getDay()) }
}
)
```

While **weekday** and **timeOffset** are document fields.
This query works just fine in MongoDB shell. I'm trying to find out a way to write this query in Java 8.
I've tried the following:

```
BasicDBObject query =  new BasicDBObject("stopDate",new BasicDBObject("$gte", currDate))
                .append("startDate",new BasicDBObject("$lte", currDate))
                .append("weekday",
                        new BasicDBObject("$where", () ->
                        {
                            return (this.weekday == currDate + this.timeOffset)
                        }));
```

However I can't even compile this code. Java **this** is not recognized.
Is there a way to accomplish the query in Java?

Thanks in advance for help!

Answer (score 1):

Ok,

I've figured out an alternative solution for the same query. Since the following Javascript query is equivalent to the posted one:

```
var currDate = new ISODate()
db.getCollection('rides')
.find(
{
    "startDate" : {
        "$lte" : currDate
    },
    "stopDate" : {
        "$gte" : currDate
     },
    $where : 'this.weekday == new Date(new Date().getTime() + this.timeOffset).getDay()'
})
```

I could just write the same in Java:

```
BasicDBObject query =  new BasicDBObject("stopDate",new BasicDBObject("$gte", currDate))
            .append("startDate", new BasicDBObject("$lte", currDate))
            .append("$where", "this.weekday == new Date(new Date().getTime() + this.timeOffset).getDay()");
```

And it perfectly worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
Document whereDoc = new Document(
    "$where",
    "function(){var j=false; [2,4].forEach(i=>{if([4,5].indexOf(i)>-1){j=true;}}); return j;}"
);

Query query = new BasicQuery(whereDoc);
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("ent_id").is("google"));
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("app_id").is("pic"));
List<Map> result = mongoTemplate.find(query, Map.class, "googletest");
```

Comment: Answers are usually more helpful if you can explain what you did and why instead of just pasting a wall of code. Also this doesn't really look like the query that was asked about (there are no dates and other fields are being queried on).